# What is the Clojure equivalent of Scala's seq.reduceOption?

Tags: scala, clojure, reduce

In Scala's Collections library - we see the [Seq Class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.Seq) which has the reduceOption method:

```
def reduceOption[A1 >: A](op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): Option[A1]
```

> Reduces the elements of this sequence, if any, using the specified associative binary operator."

This has [another great explanation here](http://tactechs.tumblr.com/post/29739228649/scala-reduce-for-possibly-empty-collections):

> Here comes `reduceOption` to save the day! If the `reduce` would fail because the collection was empty, it will just return a `None` instead, and a `Some(returnvalue)` for nonempty collections.

My question is: **What is the Clojure equivalent of Scala's seq.reduceOption?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simply called reduce:

```
user> (reduce + (range 1e6))
499999500000  

user> (reduce + [])
0
```

In the second case the result of zero comes form the fact that the identity value for addition is zero, so if you call the `+` function with no arguments it will return 0. for `*` the return value would be one. This requires that the function you pass be able to handle being called with zero, one, or two arguments. You can prevent this behavior by specifying the initial value as a third argument, in which case your reducing function is never called if the list is empty.

```
user> (reduce * -1 [])
-1
```

Reduce also uses the forkjoin framework when called on collections that support this such as vectors.

Comment: From where is it getting that the type is integer when applied to an empty sequence?

Comment: I'll expand the answer to talk about types.

Comment: Reduce with no initial value and an empty sequence will invoke the reduce function with no args. And (+) returns 0.

Comment: To a Scala programmer this seems overly restrictive. Do I need distinct operators to reduce by summing over a sequence of floats or doubles or rationals or (if you believe it's applicable) strings?

Comment: `reduce` is provided a function (Clojure has no concept of "operator"). You get what the function does when called on successive values from the colleciton.

Comment: `(reduce str ["this" "is" "stringy"])` -> "thisisstringy" `(reduce str [])` -> ""

Comment: Of course. Scala treats functions or methods uniformly regardless whether their names look like operators or not. But the point remains: Clojure seems lacking in polymorphisms that are very powerful and useful in Scala.

Comment: Clojure explicitly has a "small number of data types and large number of functions" design goal. So rather than overloading an operator on a proliferation of types or classes, you create more functions between the standard ones. So overloading is rarely seen. And overloading would not be the job of `reduce`, it would be the job of the individual function (which could be a multimethod defined by `defmulti` if you want to work that way).

Comment: @RandallSchulz To answer your question, `+` is overloaded to work on the entire numeric tower -- integers, floats, rationals, BigInts, BigDecimals, etc. -- e.g. `(reduce + [1/2 1/3 1/5]) ;=> 31/30`. For each of these `0` is the identity element under addition, which is why `(+)` and thus `(reduce + [])` produce `0`. In this sense `0` is overloaded in that it is automatically coerced to the correct type 0, 0.0, 0/1, etc., when added to another. Clojure does not overload `+` to also mean string concatenation. The identity element of string concatenation is the empty string, so `(str) => ""`.